# Updating the State of a CBPeripheral in Array

Tags: swiftui, core-bluetooth

I am storing some bluetooth peripherals (CBPeripheral) in an array. The array is @Published, in an @ObservableObject so I can view the peripherals as they populate in the interface like this:

```
ForEach(0 ..< devices.count, id: \.self) { value in
    Text("name: \(self.devices[value].name ?? "no name") state: \(self.devices[value].state.rawValue))")
}
Button(action: {
    print("devices are: \(String (describing: self.BLE.devices))")
}) {
    Text("Prints correct states")
}
```

The central manager delegate does the following to store the devices as they are found :

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    self.devices.append(peripheral)
    centralManager.connect(peripheral!, options: nil)
}
```

The issue is that I cannot find a way to get a binding to the state value. Only when an item is added or removed form the array does the state refresh correctly. I understhand that this is because the array is @Published and the states themselves are not. But sureley there is some method for getting a wrapper on a property in a existing class?

Comment: You need to create a publisher for any properties you want to observer. You can create a publisher to [work with kvo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/performing-key-value-observing-with-combine). You will need to create an object to "wrap" the `CBPeripheral` and store instances of that object in your array.

Comment: I've implemented the `NSKeyValueObservation` as per the link you included. And it is printing out the changes correctly as per the Apple example, so that's great! But, it is still unclear to me what the "wrap" of the `CBPeripheral` should look like.

Comment: Essentially an object that has a CBPeripheral as a property. You can use the object to create the KVO publisher when it is initialised with a peripheral.  This object can be an `ObservableObject`