# Core Bluetooth CBPeripheralState doesn't update when connected

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-bluetooth

Okay so basically, I'm trying to write the status of my device. When pressing it, it connects, at first it says Not Connected as it should, but when connecting it just gets stuck on Connecting instead of switching to Connected when it successfully connected.
I'm pretty sure it just doesn't update the view.

How can I fix it?

```
@Binding var peripheral: CBPeripheral!
@Binding var pincode: String

let id: Int

var stateString: String {
    
    switch peripheral.state {
    case .disconnected:
        return "Not Connected"
    case .connecting:
        return "Connecting"
    case .connected:
        return "Connected"
    case .disconnecting:
        return "Disconnecting"
    @unknown default:
        return "Unknown"
    }
}

var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text(String(id))
            Spacer()
            Text(peripheral.name ?? "name" )
            Spacer()
            Text(stateString)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            NavigationLink(destination: DeviceSettingsView(pincode: $pincode, deviceName: peripheral.name!)) {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                
                
        }
        .padding()
        .font(.headline)
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe it's successfully connected if the state hasn't changed? How are you connecting? How are you checking the the state? How are you updating the view? You probably want to show the code for your SwiftUI View. That's probably where your mistake is; you probably have done something like tried to put the CBCentralManager directly in the View, which is a common mistake. But we can't really help without some concrete details.

Comment: Well, I know because I adde a tap gesture to some text in the view to view its debug description and it says connected, adde some code , and I made a separate bluetoothManager class, also the connection works perfectly and I manage to send info. this whole view is inside my devices view where I can see devices available and connected devices. if you want it I can post it just don't want to flood everything with code

Comment: The state change doesn't trigger the Binding to change. You have to observe the KVO notifications. See the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402748/updating-the-state-of-a-cbperipheral-in-array

Comment: This looks like a pretty good tutorial on bridging KVO to SwiftUI via Combine: https://augmentedcode.io/2020/11/08/observing-a-kvo-compatible-model-in-swiftui-and-mvvm/

Comment: I took a look at KVO, but I'm not sure where to add it, I tried adding it to my peripheral var in BluetoothManager class, but it gives me `Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`

Comment: I found this tutorial super helful a few months ago when I was trying to hookup my iphone to a bluetooth device. Try taking a look at this tutorial if you haven't already: https://learn.adafruit.com/build-a-bluetooth-app-using-swift-5/scanning-for-peripherals.

Comment: Can you also include more of your code? It's hard to see what the problem is when you didn't include the `startScanning()`, `centralManagerDidUpdateState()`, `didDiscover()`, `didConnect()` functions for the CBCentralManager.